# How can I maintain a chaining of results approach while performing a non-blocking wait?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

**Background**:

I use a Result class that lets me chain success and failure lambdas together. For example:

```
var result = DoSomething();
result.OnSuccess(() => DoSomethingElse()).OnFailure(() => LogFailure());
```

One of the OnSuccess functions I have is:

```
public Result<T> OnSuccess<T>(Func<Result<T>> func)
{
    if (!this.Success)
    {
        return Fail<T>(this);
    }

    return func();
}
```

**Problem**:

I have an ask to support *async* lambdas, like so:

```
public Result<T> OnSuccess<T>(Func<Task<Result<T>>> func)
```

Within the function, the ask is to await on the Task in a non-blocking fashion and return the result.

But, by using await, the OnSuccess function must be marked async and thus must return a `Task<Result<T>>`, which in turn breaks OnSuccess chaining.

**Question**:

How can I maintain a chaining of results approach while performing a non-blocking wait?

Comment: Have you seen the [`Then` extension methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-sequences-of-asynchronous-operations-with-tasks/)

Comment: @StephenCleary That is an awesome link, Mr Toub always shines through , i must admit this is not obvious though

Comment: @StephenCleary - Are you proposing abandoning the Result class in favor of Then, or is there a way of combining them? One challenge for replacing Result with Then is we're using Result to propagate custom return codes to a caller, which Then doesn't seem to support.

Comment: You can use something like `Then` to chain `Task<Result<T>>` instances.